# Issue downloading csv file from website in Python

Tags: python, csv, urllib

So I am trying to download and write a csv file onto my computer from a site that requires my Email Address and password as authentication for the site. I have the following code:

```
import cStringIO
import pycurl
import urllib

url = 'http://www.riglocator.ca/report=rig%2Frig%2D150226%2Ecsv'



def GetPage(url, proxy=None):
  if proxy:
    port = 8888
    proxy = proxy.replace("socks://", "")
    if ":" in proxy:
      port = int(proxy.rsplit(":", 1)[1])
      proxy = proxy.rsplit(":", 1)[0]
  try:
    buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
    c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
    c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 8)
    if proxy:
      c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, proxy)
      c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, port)
      c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
      c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'john@mail.com:password123')
    c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    results = buf.getvalue()
    buf.close()
  except:
    results = ""
  return results

GetPage(url,"socks://127.0.0.1:8888")

def loader():
    csv_url = GetPage(url,"socks://127.0.0.1:8888")
    r = urllib.urlopen(csv_url)
    print(r)
    csv = r.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split('\\n')
    dest_url = r'mapfile.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, 'w')
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + '\n')
    fx.close()

loader()
```

But this still returns the HTML code from the login page, any suggestions?

I am getting this error:

```
     File "C:/Users/cevans/PycharmProjects/RigLocatorMapPull/rigmapscrape.py", line 55, in <module>
loader()
  File "C:/Users/cevans/PycharmProjects/RigLocatorMapPull/rigmapscrape.py", line 44, in loader
    r = urllib.urlopen(csv_url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 463, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 477, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some code I wrote to grab a file with pycurl, it should do basically what you need to do.  You just need to add the option c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'username:userpass') do my code to set your username and password.

http://prestongarrison.com/proper-python-pycurl-example/

Comment: what is the difference between using pycurl and requests library for this? I guess what im asking is...is it possible to keep the code and library I have been using?

Comment: Yes you could, but pycurl is based on a very old library that  has been very highly tested and maintained.  I use a lot of these things in high production, and have found requests can cause dead locks, and some other weird issues.   So I tend to stay away from it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well I am running Python 2.7 W64bit and cant seem to find pycurl for 64bit. Second, adding the username and password, would I add this under the try: statement? Does this line of code work for both username and password?

Comment: Yes should work for both, if you installed pip just type pip install pycurl, if you don't have pip installed google how to install it.  The best thing about python is all the third part libraries available to you.  Pip allows you to easily install most of these libraries.  Just add the username and password option in the code where i do all the other setopt, right before i call perform.

Comment: Looks like I have your code working but this still is returning the HTML from the login page. Any idea why this isnt working for the username and password? Here ill edit what I have.

Comment: Well if they are having you actually type in a login and password, not using http  authentication this gets much more complicated..

Comment: Is it a true web password, or does it have you type in login and password on page.  If this is the case its more complicated, you need to figure out what fields to submit to the form, etc

Comment: Im not entirely sure how to check, here Preston I will PM you the link if you know how to check. Excuse my ignorance, im not a programmer by trade.

Comment: So yes this page submits fields to a form.  Google "curl submit form fields"  It may be as simple as just submitting form fields, or it could b e way more complicated.   Look into mechanize this will allow you to more automate web pages like this.  It is probably a better choice for what you are trying to do.  Mechanize + beautiful soup is a very good combination to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is a solution using the Mechanize browser library which takes the url, 
#changes it to the current date, submits the username/password in a form, 
#downloads a csv and writes it to a folder location: 

__author__ = 'cevans'

import mechanize
import os
import cookielib
import datetime, string

USERNAME = 'xxxx'
PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
OLDURL = 'http://www.oldurl.com/report050301'
folder = r'\\Driver'

def loader():
#Takes current date and changes URL to grab correct datefile (Schedule only runs on day of week)
    cdate = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%y%m%d"))
    DATAURL = string.replace(OLDURL,'150301',cdate)

# Browser and Cookie Jar
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)
# Browser options
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(False)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(True)
# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
# Opens site:
    r = br.open(DATAURL)
    html = r.read()
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['nauthemail']= USERNAME
    br.form['password']=PASSWORD
    br.submit()
    r = br.open(DATAURL)
#Read and write file to csv, in folder

    csv = r.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split('\\n')
    fname = 'map-'+ cdate
    base_filename=fname
    filename_suffix = '.csv'
    folder1 = os.path.join(folder, base_filename + filename_suffix)
    dest_url = folder1
    fx = open(dest_url, 'w')
    for line in lines:
    fx.write(line + '\n')
    fx.close()

loader()
```